# Can't write AJAX output variable in html form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to print inside a span tag ("estimation2") the result of a calculation (for now, just a simple sum of the two input boxes "SHm2" and "STm2"). I'm using an AJAX call to perform that task. It seems to work perfectly until the alert, which shows the correct result, but for some reasons I can't write that result in my html form. I've been looking around and tried several things, yet none of them worked. For instance I've tried using the write method but it didn't work or stuff like `$("#estimation2").html(estimation);` or
`document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = estimation;`
The only way I managed to get it written was by using `window.onload`, but this generates the calculation when the page loads, and I don't want that. I only want the AJAX code to be triggered when I click on my button. 
Also, just for info, the calculation is made in my django view, even though I don't think it's relevant here as it looks to work properly. I'm really lost here, could you please help?

Here is my html code and the AJAX script:

```
<input type="text" id="SHm2" name="SHm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">
<input type="text" id="STm2" name="STm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">

<button id="estimation" name= "estimation" onclick="calculate()">Estimation</button>

<label>Result:</label>
<span id="estimation2"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate () {
      var SHm2 = $('#SHm2').val();
      var STm2 = $('#STm2').val();
      $.ajax({
              url: '/myApp/templates/homepage/',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                'SHm2':SHm2,
                'STm2':STm2,
                estimation: 'estimation',
              },
              success: function(estimation) {
              alert(estimation);
              document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = estimation;
              }
      }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try setting the text content of `estimation2` by using `$("#estimation2").text(estimation);`

Comment: Your code works as it is, provided the span element exists at the time you're trying to write to it. Make sure it exists (you should see an error in the console, if it doesn't exist), and also make sure the id is unique, and the element is visible (use Inspect Element to check the CSS attached to the element).

Comment: @Abdullah Abid: unfortunately it didn't work as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try placing everything in the script inside `$(document).ready(function(){ Code here }`  , also does the alert show the response data?

Comment: @Teemu: you might be up to something indeed. I've made a quick test and put my span tag before the button. I indeed got a small variation. After the alert, I can briefly see "[Object object]" being displayed and then it disappears. So I guess that's an improvement, but it still doesn't print my result. Also, I'm only getting this if I use (as per Abdullah Abid's suggestion): document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = $("#estimation2").text(estimation);

Comment: Just tried `$(document).ready(function() { Code here }` but it didn't work. It doesn't trigger the AJAX call anymore as I don't get the alert.

Comment: I think you misinterpret what i was trying to say instead of using `document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = $("#estimation2").text(estimation);` just use `$("#estimation2").text(estimation);` and also instead of using an `alert`  try  `console.log` that should print the response in the console

Comment: OK, that means your button is in a form, and the form is submitted. Add `type="button"` to the `#estimation` button to prevent the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you wanna do is run the JS after the HTML document has loaded, and as mentioned in the comment section you need to add `type="button"` to `estimation` button

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="SHm2" name="SHm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">
<input type="text" id="STm2" name="STm2" maxlength="10" type="number" value="50">

<button id="estimation" name= "estimation" type="button" onclick="calculate()" >Estimation</button>

<label>Result:</label>
<span id="estimation2"></span>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   function calculate() {
    var SHm2 = $("#SHm2").val();
    var STm2 = $("#STm2").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/myApp/templates/homepage/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        SHm2: SHm2,
        STm2: STm2,
        estimation: "estimation"
      },
      success: function(estimation) {
        console.log(estimation);
        document.getElementById("estimation2").innerHTML = estimation;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: As per Teemu's answer, I simply needed to add type="button" to my button tag. Your answer only misses onclick="calculate()". Just edit your comment and I'll mark this as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @curiousIT you can either use `onclick="calculate()"` or use an onclick event handler(the way i did it) , works either way :)